# SQL: Select supplier that delivers all products in specific category

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Lets say i have 3 tables:

**- supplier**
 - suppliercode
 - suppliername

**- offer**
 - suppliercode
 - productid

**- product**
 - product id
 - category

How can i select suppliers that offer **all** products from a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

You should look sql division.

Offer divied by all product from your category should give you the result.

Select supplier and all it's product in one category

Divide last request by all product from one category

**EDIT :** add example give all suplier selling all fr category product

Look at the example I have made http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87adfc/16

remark : Please I don't use the best way to make sql division